# Extremely CPU intensive task replacing an ImageView every 50ms

Tags: android

edit: Added a bounty. Hopefully this will draw some attention to the issue at hand.

I am currently trying to solve a problem in which an animation is continuously run on the main screen of an application animating a baby sleeping. this is done by having an imageView and replacing the current image in the animation with the next in line. Seing as there are more than 500 images this becomes very CPU intensive as each time an image is replaced the entire View Hierachy is re-calculated. Is there any way to NOT recalculate the entire view hierachy during this animation?

The run method looks like this :

```
        @Override
    public void run() {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        final String name = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, pattern, current);
        final int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
        if (id != 0) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        current++;
        if (runAgain()) {
            frameCounter++;
            long nextAt = firstFrameAt + (frameCounter * interval);
            long delay = nextAt - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - 1;
            if (delay > 0) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            } else {
                this.run();
            }
        }
    }
```

edit: I've been thinking about creating my own custom ImageView and overriding whatever method  causes the problem. Would this be a viable solution?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why don't you use a video instead?

Comment: Going off of what @Brad said, how does an animated GIF sound?

Comment: 500 odd frames with a maximum of 256 colours? Seems just as bad. :(

Comment: Animated gif just means putting the preasure on the memory instead. I tried a similar solution and was met with an OutOfMemory exception when attempting to run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by implementing my own custom ImageView overriding the following two methods:

```
@Override
public void setImageBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

        // The currently set Drawable
        Bitmap oldBitmap = null;
        try
        {
            oldBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)this.getDrawable()).getBitmap();   
        }catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.d("setImageBitmap", "oldBitmap is null");
        }

        if (null != oldBitmap && oldBitmap != bitmap) {
            final int oldWidth = oldBitmap.getWidth();
            final int oldHeight = oldBitmap.getHeight();

            /**
             * Ignore the next requestLayout call if the new Bitmap is the
             * same size as the currently displayed one.
             * */
            mIgnoreNextRequestLayout = oldHeight == bitmap.getHeight()
                    && oldWidth == bitmap.getWidth();
        }
    }

    super.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

@Override
public void requestLayout() {
    if (!mIgnoreNextRequestLayout) {
        super.requestLayout();
        Log.d("RequestLayout", "Requesting new layout");
    }
    else
        Log.d("RequestLayout", "Ignoring next requestLayout");

    // Reset Flag so that the requestLayout() will work again
    mIgnoreNextRequestLayout = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override ImageView and (at a minimum) its onDraw() method, using Canvas.drawBitmap to draw the bitmap.

Using a background thread, you can pre-fetch images and create a small FIFO queue of bitmaps, then use a timer mechanism to trigger the next draw of the next bitmap in the queue.

Comment: How does that solve the problem of the application recalculating the entire view hierachy when the image is replaced with a new one ?

Comment: an owner drawn control can control handling of layout, drawing, measuring, etc.   You'll really just subclass View, not ImageView, and directly draw using Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, just block the layout request. override onRequestLayout and don't call the super. You will probably have to do some manual onLayout in your parent to set the proper sizes (or override the layout method if you're ICS...can't in 2.x as its marked as final). make sense?

An example of my container view:

```
@Override
public void requestLayout() {

}

// i'm ignoring the widths/heights here an manually setting it to what i know it should be. The children DO need a layout initially or their widths will be 0 and not show. 
 // 

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)getChildAt(i);
        iv.layout(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

so now every time a change happens in the child I don't have to revalidate the entire view hierarchy as I know the dimensions didn't change. This saves a ton of CPU on the device. You may also want to consider something like this: [Optimized Image View](http://www.senab.co.uk/2013/01/17/snippet-imageview-layout-optimisation/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of `ImageView`:

```
/**
 * Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.
 * 
 * @param drawable The drawable to set
 */
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (mDrawable != drawable) {
        mResource = 0;
        mUri = null;

        int oldWidth = mDrawableWidth;
        int oldHeight = mDrawableHeight;

        updateDrawable(drawable);

        if (oldWidth != mDrawableWidth || oldHeight != mDrawableHeight) {
            requestLayout();
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}

/**
 * Sets a Bitmap as the content of this ImageView.
 * 
 * @param bm The bitmap to set
 */
@android.view.RemotableViewMethod
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    // if this is used frequently, may handle bitmaps explicitly
    // to reduce the intermediate drawable object
    setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
}
```

It is clear that there is a check for the bounds of the new Bitmap you're supplying to decide whether to request layout.

```
        if (oldWidth != mDrawableWidth || oldHeight != mDrawableHeight) {
            requestLayout();
        }
```

According to your description, I believe your images should be of the exact same size since you're almost creating a movie effect. So, check their sizes. If they have the same sizes already, you should check if really `the entire View Hierachy is re-calculate`!

Side notes:

- You should probably check the sizes of your images: Big images' decoding is also CPU intensive.
- I would advice you to decode the next image on a separate thread then set it if the 50 ms have passed or wait until they have passed. In other words, do not wait for your handler, decode the next image and notify when the decoding is done.
- You are calling `recycle` on the bitmap! Please check the documentation: *`This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more references to this bitmap.`* I am unsure if recycling is very intensive but follow the documentation in this case and do not call it.